# Cannot post API request from Postman to database using express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, postman

This is my server.js:

```
const express= require('express');
const app = express();
// const mongoose= require('mongoose');

// load config from env file
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// middleware to parse json request body
app.use(express.json());

// import routes for Todo API
const todoRoutes = require('./routes/todo');
// mount the todo API routes
 app.use("api/v1", todoRoutes);
// now the server 
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log(`server started on port 3000`)
})
// connect to the database 
const dbConnect= require('./config/database');
dbConnect();

// default route
app.get("/",((res)=>{
    res.send(`<h1> This is the home page</h1>`)
}))
```

And this is my database.js  --

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
require("dotenv").config();

const dbConnect=()=>{
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL,{
useNewUrlParser:true,
useUnifiedTopology:true

})
.then(()=>console.log("connection ho gya "))
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log("connction nhi hua ")
    console.error(error.message)
    // process.exit(1);
    
})
}
module.exports = dbConnect;
```

And this is my Todo.js --

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Here is the schema --> todoSchema 
const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String, // type of data in the title 
    required: true,
    maxLength: 50, 
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxLength: 50, // maximum length of the description
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now(), //default value 
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});
// this statement is required for exporting the model 
// and this is exporting the todoSchema but with the name "Todo"
module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
```

And this is my createTodo.js --

```
const Todo = require("../models/Todo");

// defining route handler

exports.createTodo = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // extract title and description from request body
    const { title, description } = req.body;
    // create a new Todo Object and insert in Database
    const response = await Todo.create({ title, description });
    // send a json response with a success flag
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: response,
      message: "Entry created successfully",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      data: "internal server error",
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

And this is my todo.js --

```
const express= require('express');
const router=express.Router();
// importing controllers
const { createTodo } = require('../controllers/createTodo');
// defining routes
router.post('/createTodo',createTodo );
// exporting
module.exports = router;
```

Now whenever I am sending data from Postman API app to my database, I am getting this --

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/createTodo</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

and data is not getting inserted in my database

I am unable to get why I am unable to get success flag in response and send data to database

Comment: Things I've already tried:

->Checked and rechecked the URL entered in Postman (http://localhost:3000/api/v1/createTodo)
->Set the URL type in Postman to POST
->Made sure the URL was properly registered, and compared with working URLs and files.
Even after this, nothing has worked so far. I am fairly new to this, so that might be the cause of my oversight, please do let me know if you can spot where it's going wrong.

Comment: Are there any logs on your node server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement `app.use("api/v1", todoRoutes);` in `server.js` is missing a `/` in the `"api/v1"` string.

It should be `"/api/v1"`.

You can learn more about [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) in the Express documentation.